# Could I set value in CLCircularRegion?

Tags: swift, swift4, clcircularregion

I'm developing app using `CLCircularRegion`.

I want to set value in `CLCircularRegion`. So I did `region.setValue(forKey:key)` but it showed

```
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            for obj in pushInfoArr! {
                let localLatiStr = obj["local_latit"] as! String
                let localLongitStr = obj["local_longit"] as! String
                let localMsg = obj["local_mesg"] as! String
                let url = obj["cnnct_url"] as! String
                let localLati = Double(localLatiStr)
                let localLongi = Double(localLongitStr)
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(localLati!, localLongi!)
                region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: 1000, identifier: localMsg)
                region.setValue(localMsg, forKey: "msg")
                region.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
                region.notifyOnEntry = true
                self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
            }
    }
```

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key bb"

Could I set value(url) in `CLCircularRegion`??

Comment: Please show the code that you are using. What value do you want to set? Bounding box ("bb")? You can simply set the radius by `clRegion.radius = 123.4` - the centre similarly. See here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clcircularregion

Comment: updated question! 
I want to set url and message to show notifications.
And when I run the app through notifications, I want to go to the saved url

Comment: As far as I can see neither `CLCircularRegion` nor `CLRegion` from which it inherits has properties `msg` nor `url` - so you can't use `setValue` to set those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift isn't Javascript - you can't create new properties on an existing class or struct, and neither `CLCircularRegion` nor `CLRegion` from which it inherits has properties `msg` nor `url`.

You have misconstrued what `setValue` does - it is a method on the base class `NSObject` which allows the setting of an *existing* property of the class by reference to its "name" or key. Its use is not recommended in Swift (it's an Objective-C legacy).

What you need to do is to create a struct or subclass that holds both your region and your required properties:

Either

```
struct MyRegion {
    var region: CLCircularRegion
    var msg: String
    var url: String
}
```

or

```
class MyRegion: CLCircularRegion {
    var msg: String
    var url: String
    init(centre: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, identifier: String, msg: String, url: String) {
        super.init(centre: centre, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
        self.msg = msg
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

p.s. don't use 'url' as the name of a property that isn't a `URL` - call it 'urlString' or some such. I just used that to correspond to your question's terminology.

Answer (score 0):

No, CLCircularRegion doesn't have a property called url, so you can't set url on objects of that type.

Comment: No way to save url? 
Is only identifier available?